# Modifying 2D char array passed to a function in C

Tags: c, arrays

Lacking money ATM so I'm offering $0.25 via paypal to the first person to point out what I did wrong in this code snippet -- I hope this doesn't violate the site rules or insult anybody.

I want to modify an multi-dimensional array in a function. It gets modified while in the function, but when scope returns to the main function the array is unchanged.

The function headers cannot be modified. Thanks for helping me out.

```
void getAlignment(char*s1, char*s2, char*s3, char*aligned[])
{
    /***********************
    Code here which assigns
    char**tmp to "different" "words"
    ***********************/

printf("tmp in getAlignment function\n");
printf("%s %s\n", tmp[0], tmp[1]); // prints "different words", as expected
    aligned = tmp;
}

int main(void)
{
    // skipped some code

    char** aligned = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*2);
    aligned[0] = "should";
    aligned[1] = "change";

    printf("%s %s\n", aligned[0], aligned[1]); // prints "should change", as expected
    getAlignment(s1, s2, transcript, aligned); // how do i change aligned during this call?
    printf("%s %s\n", aligned[0], aligned[1]); // prints "should change"

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: what you want to do in getAlignment() function? What is the expected output?

Comment: The idea is i have `aligned` in `main`, and I want to change it in `getAlignment` by having it point to stuff which the `getAlignment` method changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write inside `getAlignment`:

```
aligned = (char**) malloc(2*sizeof(char*));
```

you are making the pointer `GetAlignment::aligned` point to some new memory. It no longer points to the memory that `main::aligned` points to.  When you operate on this new memory, it has no effect on the memory that `main::aligned` was and is pointing to.

(Note - the `::` is not C syntax, but my meaning is to disambiguate your two variables which are both called `aligned` in their local scope, despite the fact that they are two separate variables).

If your intent is that the code in `getAlignment`modifies the memory being pointed to by `main::aligned` then just remove the above line.

If your intent is that `getAlignment` be able to allocate new memory, and `main::aligned` be switched to use that new memory, then you have to pass `main::aligned` by reference (i.e. add an extra level of indirection in the function call). And don't forget to `free()` the previously-allocated memory.

BTW [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: this "pointed" me in the right direction (bu dum pshhh). please let me know your paypal in case you'd like small compensation for your help. thanks very much.

Comment: Idon't use paypal... it's evil. happy to help for free anyway

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to allocate 2D array again by `aligned = (char**) malloc(2*sizeof(char*));` in function `getAlignment` because you already allocated it in main.

You require allocate each element of array like

```
int alignedStrLen = strlen(s3);
aligned[0] = malloc((alignedStrLen+1)*sizeof(char));
aligned[0][alignedStrLen] = '\0';
aligned[1] = malloc((alignedStrLen+1)*sizeof(char));
aligned[1][alignedStrLen] = '\0';
```

And and you should free the memory allocated by `malloc`.

Comment: let's say in `main` i just declared `char**aligned` w/out initializing it. The idea is i want the function `getAlignment` to modify `aligned` regardless of what `aligned` points to.